# input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2

Tags: python

```
Jamil= input(C1,"Enter your strength:")
print(C1,"Enter your strength:")
Ahmed= input(C1,"Enter your skill:")
print(C1,"Enter your skill:")
```

It gives me an error of `input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2` and I do not know how to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

By listening to the error message and passing only *one* argument to `input()`:

```
Jamil = input(str(C1) + " Enter your strength:")
```

or use string formatting:

```
Jamil = input("{} Enter your strength:".format(C1))
```

Only the `print()` function supports a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

`input()` only takes 1 argument.

See this help (*interactive interpreter*):

```
>>> help(input)
Help on built-in function input in module builtins:

input(...)
    input([prompt]) -> string

    Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
    If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
    On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
    is printed without a trailing newline before reading.
```

The `help()` builtin is a handy tool for finding out things in Python.
You can type: `help(...)` on almost anything to get help (*if available*).

Answer (score 1):

You passed 2 arguments to the input() function and it expects only one.